# How does one configure mercurial hg to not retain backups by default?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I never use those .orig files, and I hate cleaning them up manually.  Is there a way to configure `hg revert` to use the `--no-backups` option by default?  I can't find it in the [Mercurial manual](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ)

Using a shell alias is possible but isn't desirable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create an alias in your config file.

More details on the config file at http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html

Read the manual myself, and it looks like its changed somewhat since the last time I read it. I was going to suggest using defaults, but it appears that has been deprecated. The recommendation is to use aliases.

It appears an alias CAN override a built-in command, but obviously they don't recommend it.

So, you could do

```
[alias]
revert = revert --no-backup
```

but the recommendation would be to create a new command for yourself

Comment: I have created a new command also because I always use the --all option.. so that gives:
[alias]
revertall = revert --all --no-backup

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the best way is to include the following two lines in your .hgrc file:

```
[defaults]
revert = --no-backup
```

Comment: "[defaults are deprecated. Don't use them. Use aliases instead](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#defaults)"